# proof of continuity implies reimann integrable without using uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Many of the proofs that continuity implies Reimann integrability actually uses uniform continuity because by convention, the Riemann integral is usually defined on a closed interval [a,b] which is compact. But as many have pointed out, if we integrate over (a,b) instead, we would get the same result since changing a finite number of points does not change the value of the integral, but since (a,b) is not compact, we can't use uniform continuity as part of our proof. so basically, can we prove that continuity implies Reimann integrable without using uniform continuity?

Comment: Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ doesn't blow up at $a$ or $b$. Then you can show that $f$ is integrable on $[a + \epsilon, b - \epsilon]$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon > 0$ by same proof. Hence any partition  $P$ of $(a,b)$ is now a partition of $[a + \epsilon, b - \epsilon]$ plus 2 infinitesimal intervals. Can you conclude?

Comment: Do we use the Cauchy criterion to show the 2 infinitesimal intervals are negligible? Upper Sum - Lower Sum < epsilon? I can't think of any other theorem that we can use. Or can we say the  2 infinitesimal intervals are negligible because they have measure 0 and don't make any difference?

Comment: You do not need to invoke uniform continuity to prove Riemann integrablility. I believe Spivak has a proof in his $Calculus$ book.

Comment: I remember now. He proves the equality of the upper and lower Darboux integrals, which both satisfy the conditions necessary for the usual freshman calculus proof of the FTC to go through. Using this approach one has $\overline J'(x)=f(x)=\underline J'(x)$ and the result follows.